# Profiling cublas applications

Tags: c, cuda, profiling, nvidia, cublas

I'm trying to profile my application that uses cuBLAS exclusively with Nvidia Visual Profiler on Windows, however it shows that there's no GPU usage in my application at all!  That is, the timeline is completely empty except for profiling overhead.  Just to make sure someone didn't change out the security settings or something under me, I profiled an application with a kernel and `cudaMemcpy` calls, and it is profiled properly.  What gives?  Am I missing a setting?  Linking to the wrong version of cuBLAS libraries?  Or is it not actually calling the GPU (although seems completely improbable to me...)?  I'm using Intel's compiler for 64-bit support, if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling cudaDeviceSynchronize or cudaDeviceReset after you launch the kernel? The profiler needs one of these functions to be called to know when to dump the gpou records.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who runs in to this problem in the future: I had to use `cudaProfilerStart()` and `cudaProfilerStop()` around my cuBLAS function.  Just adding `cudaDeviceSyncrhonize()` didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying is actually true. I have always been able. to profile `cuBLAS` without the calls to `cudaProfilerStart()` or `cudaProfilerStop()`. Typically, calling `cudaDeviceReset()`, as pointed out by @GregSmith, is enough.

Comment: @JackOLantern You may be right, it could be an idiosyncrasy of my setup.  But, if someone else runs into the same problem this fixed it.